# Accessing Androids UpdateEngine (or other SystemApi classes) from application code

Tags: java, android, android-source

I'm trying to write a system-updater application, which uses the [UpdateEngine](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/UpdateEngine.java) of Android 7+. However, I can't seem to get access to it from my java code, since the class and its methods are marked with @SystemApi.

I integrated my application into the AOSP tree, but I can't start a successful compile from my application directory: When i run **mm** in the app dir, I directly get the following error:

> The import android.os.UpdateEngine cannot be resolved

This also happens if I just add the import statement to an already existing aosp system-app, e.g.

What is the correct way to use UpdateEngine (or actually any other @SystemApi) from an application? I don't want to change the android api by removing all the SystemApi and break compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course I find the solution right after posting the question...

In case someone else stumbles upon this in the future - The problem was that I had the following SDK version defined in my Android.mk:

> LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

System APIs (and thus UpdateEngine) became accessible after changing the sdk version as follows:

> LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := system_current

Comment: Is it required to have an .mk or .bp file if you want to access SystemApis? Does this involve using the NDK? I'm following the OTA updater sample (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample/), but it's pretty vague on how to access the UpdateEngine APIs.

Comment: Hi Simon. Sorry for the late response, but currently you need an .mk file. And you need to build your app in the AOSP tree, there is no support for UpdateEngine in the standalone NDK (which you get with android studio).

Comment: Hi @andreas-hofmann is there a guide to build your app in the AOSP tree? sorry for the maybe basic question, but I'm starting with AOSP and IoT, thanks in advance.